# Byte array to String back to byte array - Performance wise

Tags: java, android, performance, arrays

I receive a `byte[]` with data in it (Which is a `String` that was converted into a `byte[]`). I need to check if the `byte[]` contains a `String`. Something like (pseudo code):

```
byte[] b = ...;
b.contains("something");
```

if it contain "something" then I need to split that `byte[]` into smaller `byte[]`'s and later join all the smaller `byte[]`'s into a single `byte[]`

I would do it like this:

```
    // fileData is my original byte[]
    final String fileDataStr = new String(fileData, "UTF-8");
    final ArrayList<byte[]> list1 = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    final ArrayList<byte[]> list2 = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    final ArrayList<byte[]> list3 = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    if(fileDataStr.contains("VERSION:"))
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(BEGIN:VCARD.*?END:VCARD)", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(fileDataStr);

        while (m.find()) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Getting vcard per vcard");
            final String subVcard = m.group(1);

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
            Matcher m2 = p.matcher(subVcard);

            // Search for the vcard version
            if (m2.find()) 
            {
                if("2".equalsIgnoreCase(m2.group(1)))
                {
                    list1.add(subVcard.getBytes());
                }
                else if("3".equalsIgnoreCase(m2.group(1)))
                {
                    list2.add(subVcard.getBytes());
                }
                else if("4".equalsIgnoreCase(m2.group(1)))
                {
                    list3.add(subVcard.getBytes());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "No vcard version found!");
            }
        }
    }

    // Convert the ArrayList to an Array
    final Object[] aux1 = list1.toArray();
    final Object[] aux2 = list2.toArray();
    final Object[] aux3 = list3.toArray();

    // Convert each array to a single byte[]
    final byte[] myByteArray = new byte[aux1.length + aux2.length + aux3.length];
    System.arraycopy(aux1, 0, myByteArray, 0, aux1.length);
    System.arraycopy(aux2, 0, myByteArray, myByteArray.length, aux2.length);
    System.arraycopy(aux3, 0, myByteArray, myByteArray.length, aux3.length);

    // The inputstream
    final InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray);
```

What I thought to do to solve this problem is convert the original byte[] into a String. Compare the String with my "something" and re-convert the String's back to byte[] but I feel like this is not the most efficient way, or am I wrong?

I'm working with big `String` on Android and I need this do have a decent performance.

Any advices?

Comment: "Any advices?" - Yes. Benchmark it yourself.

Comment: what about converting the `"something"` to a byte array and looping through the larger array to see if that sub-array exists.

Comment: @MitchWheat I just want to know if this is the right approach, then I'll do the benchmarks myself. I just want to avoid running in circles if there is a better theoretical approach to this problem.

Comment: @ns47731 that's why I asked it here, good idea. I'll test that out!